# Macbook Pro (2017) USB-C to 2 x Thunderbolt Displays - Adaptor Options

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, macbook, macbook-pro, usb-c

I have a new `Macbook pro (13" 2017)` arriving soon.

Currently I have 2 Apple `27" Thunderbolt` displays which I would like to continue using (I cannot switch them out as they are company equipment).

I am trying to figure out what the best way to connect my screens to the new Macbook is. The obvious solution is **Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C)** to **Thunderbolt 2** adaptor from Apple and daisy-chain displays, however, I would really like to have power through the same `USB-C` port as well so that I only need to plug in/unplug a single cable. (I know this is truly lazy but also it looks nicer...)

My ideal solution would be a Thunderbolt 3 to 2 adaptor with inline power socket. Does anyone know of anything out there?

Edit: One thought I had was whether a simple USB-C/TB3 'splitter' / 'duplicator' might give what I want, allowing power through one and thunderbolt 3 input/output on the other.

Options I have found:

`Uptab USB-C` to `Displayport` - This does not seem to be an option as;

1. its displayport rather than thunderbolt so I believe neither of the monitors would work.
2. Even if they did the USB-2/3 and Ethernet ports on the back of them would not work.

https://uptab.glopal.com/en-GB/p-73/usb-c-type-c-to-mini-displayport-adapter-4k-60hz-graphite.html?utm_campaign=en_US&utm_medium=pr&utm_source=www.uptab.com

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the power to go from wall socket to the monitor,  and from there a single cable to the laptop? With that single cable providing both power to the laptop and display information (and more) to the monitor?

Comment: Any solution which can provide a single cable input / output to laptop. I was actually thinking the more likely scenario is that there would be a USB-C input on a thunderbolt adaptor which injects power.

Comment: Your best bet is probably using [a dock](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U095-APL/) and perhaps a Thunderbolt 3-to-2 adapter. That being said, hardware recommendations are off-topic on Super User.